Could our Universe have a insanely small 'drag coefficient' that results in a non-infinite speed of light
Could our universe have some way of having a insanely small 'force' that slows down objects an incredibly small amount, but at relativistic speeds, it would restrict massless particles to a specific speed (the speed of light). Because light doesn't necessarily have a requirement to be at a certain speed, it just is at a certain speed.

if that was the case, then you would have trouble explaining how all that energy you put into accelerating the particle is not dissipated, but conserved. It should be some kind of "conservative friction". Maybe someone can make sense of it. Plus you would still need to explain time dilation and lenght contraction.

In physics (and science generally) we apply Occam's Razor when looking for solutions to problems.  You are going against that principle by replacing one relatively simple mechanism with a more complex (and unknown) mechanism that provides no way to test and no obvious advantage.

Personal theories and non-mainstream physics are off-topic here.

Photons travel at infinite proper speed (since they experience no proper time but do cover distance), which corresponds to a finite coordinate speed of $c$ in flat spacetime due to causality.

Answering off-topic questions simply encourages more off-topic questions about non-mainstream personal theories with absolutely no prior research or due diligence. The fact that the OP is an eager high-school student and physics enthusiast is great, but it isn’t a free pass to idly speculate on this site with “Could…?”  questions. The OP has enough rep to join our chat rooms if they want to toss around speculations and get feedback.

Here is my way of thinking about this. Please correct me if it is conceptually bogus:
The classical vacuum possesses both inductive and capacitive characteristics, despite being "empty" to our eyes. If we can measure those properties (and indeed we can!), we can then use them to calculate the speed with which wavelike disturbances in that "vacuum" would propagate. Maxwell did that derivation and found the speed to be none other than c.
In this sense, light is indeed "required" mathematically to have a certain speed through space, and Maxwell found it because he was a particularly smart guy. And now the coool part: his derivation for c included no term for the velocity of the reference frame in which c was derived.
In other words: you'd calculate the same value for c no matter what the baseline velocity of your laboratory was. Maxwell was that close to demonstrating special relativity!

Which way would the drag force point? If I have two masses $m$ moving at $\vec v$ and $-\vec v$, and I measure a drag force of $\vec f$ and $-\vec f$, respectively, then I am in the absolute rest-frame.
You can make a procedure for transforming from any $\vec f_1, \vec f_2$ pair to the absolute rest-frame, but how do you do the transformation? You just proved Special Relativity is wrong.
Galilean transforms should allow you to exceed $c$, so you'll have frames with cones of darkness...idk, sounds weird.

Interesting thought, but no. The speed of light had to be something, and it just so happens to be $3\times10^8$ m/s. This isn't because there is some "drag force" preventing it from being faster.

Why does it have to be finite, and specifically why can't a drag force-esk thing be the reason.

The speed of light is finite roughly because a finite amount of space is equivalent to a finite amount of time, an implication of relativity. And about a drag "force", recall that forces don't act on massless things.
